# Debugging a kernel mode driver

Tags: debugging, kmdf

I want to deploy and debug a kernel mode driver with the kernel debugger in Visual Studio 2019. Deploying and installing works and I also can start and stop the driver. But when I try to debug it, the breakpoints are ignored and the driver keeps running. Unfortunately there is no information in Google about that issue so I hope anybody of you can help me.

Thanks!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debug-universal-drivers--kernel-mode-#:~:text=Microsoft%20Windows%20Debugger%20(WinDbg)%20is,user-mode%20applications%20and%20drivers.

Comment: Thanks we´re gonna try that ;)